# What is the value of the following sums/differences of infinite ratio of products?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$1-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3\times5}{4\times8}-\frac{3\times5\times7}{4\times8\times12}+\frac{3\times5\times7\times9}{4\times8\times\times12\times16}-\dotsb $$
Seriously, I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any help is welcome.

Comment: $$T_n=(-1)^n\frac{(2n+1)!}{n! n!}\frac1{8^n}$$

Comment: So how to find this$ \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ T_{ n } } $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have from the general binomial expansion: $$\frac1{(1+x)^r} = 1-r x+\frac{r(r+1)}{1\cdot 2}x^2 - \frac{r(r+1)(r+2)}{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3}x^3 + \cdots$$

Comparing terms, we see $x = \frac12, r = \frac32$ works.

Comment: Awesome Man... How did it come to your mind? I mean what was your way of thinking? It is not to so obvious...

Comment: @MridulSachdeva  The pattern gets familiar once you see enough examples of such series.  The factors in numerator increasing by two imply r is a fraction with denominator 2, so thats easier to check.

Comment: Anyone called me?

Comment: Btw excellent. But this is very intuitive and the question maker should be hanged till death.